# Изменить часть строки в файле

Tags: bash

Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию, которая принимает в качестве параметра **имя поля**, **значение поля** и **имя файла**. Функция должна находить в файле параметр с заданным именем и менять значение этого параметра.
**Пример файла:**

```
Key1 Value1
#Key2 Value2
Key3 Value3
...
```

# закомментированная строка

Мой код не работает как надо.

```
get_field_value() {
    FIELD_VALUE=$(awk '/^# *'"$1"' +/ {gsub(/^#|^# +/,""); print $2;exit;}' $2)
}

# set field
set_field_value(){
    get_field_value $1 $2
    awk -v field_name="$1" -v field_value="$FILED_VALUE" -v change_to="$3" '{if($1==field_nam    e || $2==field_name) gsub(/.*field_value.*/, "change_to"); print}' $2
}
```

`get_field_value()` принимает имя поля и имя файла

`set_field_value()` принимает имя поля имя файла и значение для поля

Comment: Это условие - "Функция должна находить в файле параметр с заданным именем и менять значение этого параметра." Не точное. Если тип файла просто текст без разметки то зачем вам 2 параметра поиска по регулярному выражению? И дайте пример реального файла.что такое имя и значение поля? В чем разница для текстового файла.

Comment: $1 $2 $3 это "поля и знвчения" где то потерялся сам файл.

Comment: @Hellseher Пример файла /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Поле Port значение 22. $1 имя поля, $2 файл в котором меняем, $3 то на что меняем

Comment: Выходит параметров 4: 1 имя поля, 2 стаое значение, 3 новое, 4 файл

Answer (score 0):

Параметров как минимум 4

1. Ключ
2. Старе значение
3. Новое
4. Файл

Можно в одну строку:

```
 ~ $ cat test-file
key1 val1
key2 val2
key3 val1
~ $ sed -e "s/key1 *val1/key1 val-new/" test-file
key1 val-new
key2 val2
key3 val1
```

Или башом обернуть:

```
get_replace()
{
    local key=$1
    local val_old=$2
    local val_new=$3
    local file=$4

    sed -i -e "/${key} *${val_old}/${key} ${val_new}/" ${file}
}
```

Comment: Эта замена будет работать независимо от имени поля. А мне нужно менять значение конкретного поля.

Comment: О новом значении не было точного описания в вопросе, поправил